# Hide standard Edit/Remove button in Netsuite - How can i hide default netsuite buttons (Edit, Remove) from list

Tags: netsuite, erp

Hi fellow netsuite gurus,

My custom page hosts a parent record and in it i have a item sub list in a Child record. The problem happens when user tries to edit the line items by clicking on standard edit/remove  buttons available on line items in edit mode. I have tried unchecking "Allow child record edit" and "Show Remove" options in the child record settings. but for logical reasons in our program, we cannot uncheck these options. So now the question is:

**Has anyone figured out how to hide these buttons using client side code or any other setup feature?**

Comment: You can use a user event that would basically disable the option on load.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a suggestion:

1. Edit the record:

   - In Child Records subtab, do not select a tab for the child records to hide it
2. Create a saved search:

   - Check AVAILABLE AS SUBLIST VIEW.
   - In Results subtab, set OUTPUT TYPE as Result.
   - In Available Filters subtab, add the child record's field link to the parent record.
3. Edit the record, add the search as sublist view.
4. View the record and check the list, there should be no edit nor remove links.